# How do I invoke a lambda function inside a views function in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, aws-lambda

I have a Django views to create a sort of AWS pack (contains account and new vpc creation), I am trying to invoke a lambda function in between that will delete the default vpc in the newly created account. Here is my snippet :

```
   def createlab(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
       lab_name = request.POST.get('labname')
       cidr = request.POST.get('cidr')
       bill = request.POST.get('budget')
       email = request.POST.get('email')

       #CREATE ACCOUNT
       org = boto3.client('organizations')
       acc = org.create_account(
        Email=email,
        AccountName=lab_name,
        IamUserAccessToBilling='ALLOW'
       )
       time.sleep(35)
       cid = acc['CreateAccountStatus']['Id']

       #GET ACCOUNT DETAILS
       status = org.describe_create_account_status(
        CreateAccountRequestId=cid
     )
       print(status)
       time.sleep(17)
       while True:
        status = org.describe_create_account_status(CreateAccountRequestId=cid)
         try:
           accid = status['CreateAccountStatus']['AccountId']
           break
         except KeyError:
           time.sleep(40)
           accid = status['CreateAccountStatus']['State']
       #CREATE VPC
       session = 
         boto3.Session 
          (aws_access_key_id=acc_key, 
          aws_secret_access_key=sec_key,aws_session_token=token)
       ec2 = session.resource('ec2',region_name=region_ec2_sub)
       vpc = ec2.create_vpc(CidrBlock=cidr)
       id = vpc.id
      #DELETE DEFAULT VPC
      client = boto3.client('lambda',region_name='us-west-2')
      deletevpc= 
       client.invoke(FunctionName='default_vpc', 
       InvocationType='RequestResponse')
      print (deletevpc)
```

I have included a portion of my views function. I have added the #DELETE DEFAULT VPC snippet in the end. The lambda function is not getting executed. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: what is the response you're getting back?